# How to achieve Toolbar fade out affect like spotify?

Tags: android, xml

[image: describing gif]

I'm trying to achieve scrolling effect like this gif from spotify in android. I've tried and used traditional material parallax design, but can't make my mind around how to achieve this effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is called parallax effect. There are plenty of 3rd party libraries for easier implementation. But in android(preferred way)  it can be achieved as below.

**This effect is achieved by scaling in X -Y and the image or container of your views, below I show how the effect of the collapsed toolbar is achieved as spotify does.**

[image]

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/rootView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        app:elevation="0dp">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapse_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">



            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:id="@+id/background"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>


            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/below_shadow" />


            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                >




            </RelativeLayout>


            <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
                android:id="@+id/tool_bar_fg"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />


        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>


    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>


    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#121212"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">


    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>


</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

*Sorry English I had to use a translator*

Now in your activity or fragment this, listen to the changes of the slider of the appbarlayout to achieve the desired effect.

```
    app_bar_layout.addOnOffsetChangedListener(AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener { appBarLayout, verticalOffset ->

        container.translationY =
            -verticalOffset.toFloat() // Un-slide the image or container from views

        val percent =
            (Math.abs(verticalOffset)).toFloat() / appBarLayout?.totalScrollRange!! // 0F to 1F


        // Control container opacity according to offset
        //Here you can play with the values according to your requirements

        container.alpha = 1F - percent


        container.scaleY = (1F - percent) + percent / 1.199F
        container.scaleX = (1F - percent) + percent / 1.199F


    })
```

Comment: @Erick getting  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot set 'scaleY' to Float.NaN error